# Applying a javascript fade-in to 4 divs with a 2 second gap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I am trying to apply a javascript fade-in to 4 divs on a page named div1 div2 div3 and div4 (original I know) However I can not get the code below to work. I also need each fade in to have a 2 second gap between each one. Can somebody please show me how? This tiny bit of code is driving me mad now!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#div1,div2,div3,div4').ready(function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', .4).fadeTo(2000, 1.0);
}).ready(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
});
});
```

Comment: Oh that's an error, I was going by other code, I do not want a mouseover at all I want it onload but this javascript thing is all new to me! lol

Comment: Do you want to make them all fade while moving over one? Or just make the one fade out that you hover over?

Comment: @DaanHeskes I want it to happen on load, but don't know the command

Comment: $(document).ready(function() )}; does that ;) It executes all code that is in there, doesn't necessarily have to be a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fades #div1, #div2, #div3 and #div4 to 0 opacity in 2 seconds with a 2 seconds delay.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#div1').delay(2000).fadeTo(2000, 0);
$('#div2').delay(4000).fadeTo(2000, 0);
$('#div3').delay(6000).fadeTo(2000, 0);
$('#div4').delay(8000).fadeTo(2000, 0);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crc1fpey/)

Comment: Hi thanks, but I meant with a 2 second interval between each one @DaanHeskes

Comment: your amazing! as soon as I can accept your answer I will :)

Comment: do i need to call anything externally?

Answer (score 1):

One more simple version that fades in with interval of 2 seconds:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i * 2000).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zno1bw91/1/

Comment: This fades ALL elements with the class `div`, but OP only wants the id's: `div1`, `div2`, `div3` and `div4` to fade.

Comment: Thank you, upvoted. :) Don't forget updating the JSFiddle though.

Comment: @dfsq I have got no idea why I am having soooo much trouble with such a simple thing! This has taken me literally minutes to implement before now. Its driving me mad! Can you look at www.cambridgedesigncompany/index.html to tell me what I am doing wrong? Its driving me insane!

Comment: First of all you page is not available. Then you should probably ask for support Daan Heskes since you are using his code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly at my end just one error is you are not properly selecting divs.
Here is your [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/4p5j907d/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#div1,#div2,#div3,#div4').mouseover(function() {

    $(this).css('opacity', .4).fadeTo(2000, 1.0);
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(2000, 0.4);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
    * This function apply fadeIn to N elements with given interval speed
    *
    * @requires jQuery 1.x.x or higher
    *
    * @param {Array} elementsSelectors - list of selectors
    * @see 
    *   fadeInInterval(['#div1', '#div2'], 2000);
    * 
    * @param {Number} intervalMs    - the interval between fadeIn's
    * @param [{Number}] fadeInSpeed - fadeIn speed
    * @param [{Boolean}] reverse    - Reverse the direction of element foreaching to fadein.
    *   By default is false
    *
    * returns {Function} - if call this function you will cancel the interval
    * @see
    *   var cancel = fadeInInterval(['#e1', '#e2', '#e3', '#e4'], 2000, 300, true);
    *   //some on mouseOut event callback
    *   $(element).on('mouseout', function() {
    *       cancel();
    *   })
    */
    function fadeInInterval(elementsSelectors, intervalMs, fadeInSpeed, reverse) {

        $(elementsSelectors[reverse ? 'pop' : 'shift']()).stop().fadeIn(fadeInSpeed || 300);

        var intervalId = setInterval(function () {

            $(elementsSelectors[reverse ? 'pop' : 'shift']()).stop().fadeIn(fadeInSpeed || 300);

            if (!elementsSelectors.length) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
            }

        }, intervalMs);

        return function() {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        };
    }

    //Simple usage: 

    var cancel = fadeInInterval(['#div1', '#div2', '#div3', '#div4'], 2000);

    //Prevent cycle

    cancel();
```